# Como fazer com que nem todas as células de uma tableView seja editáveis?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Tenho uma tableView onde o usuário poderá deletar as células que ele selecionar. No meu caso a primeira célula da tableView não poderá ser deletada pelo usuário. Como faço para que apenas a primeira célula da tableView não seja editável?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var users = ["Todos", "User1", "User2", "User3", "User5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vasculhei o delegate da tableView e encontrei a função tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:) implementei desse jeito:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    // Todos os indíces da tableView serão editáveis para exclusão menos o primeiro (índex == 0)
    if indexPath.row != 0 {
        return .delete
    }
    return .none
}
```

Isso quebrou o galho e estava funcionando bem. Até que fuçando pelo [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62046361/6480152) achei essa solução infinitamente mais atraente:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath != 0
}
```

Acontece que usando essa função tableView(_:canEditRowAt:), além da redução do código, não faz com que as células não editáveis vão um pouco para a direita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]